# NSAttributedString does not appear when generating PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, nsattributedstring, underline

This used to work and now, all of a sudden, it stopped working:

For an iOS 7 iPad App, I generate a PDF with

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfPathWithFileName, CGRectZero, nil);
...
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Within that code block, the following methods used to render text underlined, but recently, it just stopped working and any text passed to the method is not rendered at all:

```
+(void)drawUnderlinedText:(NSString *)text withFont:(UIFont *)font andColor:(UIColor *)color andLocationX:(int)locationX andLocationY:(int)locationY andTextAreaWidth:(int)textWidth andTextAreaHeight:(int)textHeight{

    NSDictionary *attributesDict;
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString;

    attributesDict = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color, NSFontAttributeName : font, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]};
    attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributesDict];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(locationX, locationY, textWidth, textHeight);
    [attString drawInRect:rect];
}
```

I can't find anything on the web with regards to drawing to the PDF context. There are [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127828/ios-7-bug-nsattributedstring-does-not-appear) ([and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel)) that mentions that issue with regards to labels. But there doesn't seem to be a solution for my problem when generating PDF files...

Please help!

Comment: This is a bug in iOS 7. I ran into the same problem. If the attributed string has any underlined text, it won't appear in the PDF. I submitted a bug report 2 months ago.

Comment: My workaround was to remove any underline so at leat the rest of the text appears.

Comment: OK, @rmaddy I submitted a report too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a bug in iOS I decided to use the work-around from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6059069/761897) by just drawing a line to the context (see comments in code):

```
+(void)drawUnderlinedText:(NSString *)text withFont:(UIFont *)font andColor:(UIColor *)color andLocationX:(int)locationX andLocationY:(int)locationY andTextAreaWidth:(int)textWidth andTextAreaHeight:(int)textHeight{

    NSDictionary *attributesDict;
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString;

    // Commented out until iOS bug is resolved:    
    //attributesDict = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color, NSFontAttributeName : font};
    attributesDict = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color, NSFontAttributeName : font};
    attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributesDict];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(locationX, locationY, textWidth, textHeight);

    // Temporary Solution to NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName - Bug:
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);

    CGSize tmpSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 9999)];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, locationX, locationY + tmpSize.height - 1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, locationX + tmpSize.width, locationY + tmpSize.height - 1);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    // End Temporary Solution

    [attString drawInRect:rect];
}
```